# Craft CMS backend on outside parent folder

Tags: custom

I have a problem with the custom paths of my ISP Config server.
I have /www (not writable folder)
/www/private in this folder I have Craft CMS backend.
/www/web in this folder I have Craft public directory.

---

This is ISP Config host virtual website (a system tool to host many websites on Debian).
The root path is not writable.
I have an /private folder writable. I used alias @root, and I set in index.php this root path as CRAFT_BASE_PATH.
When I try to install plugins I have the following error:

```
Błąd: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/clients/client0/web7/.composer/cache) is not within the allowed path(s):
```

The web7/.composer is not writable, how to fix this issue and let CraftCMS to create .composer/cache folder in @root path.

Comment: Why this non-standard setup? What is the problem you're trying to solve? What do you need help with?

Comment: Have you checked your project root path variable in index.php and make sure composer has permissions to run in the directory?